# Disable ListBox selection through user-interface only

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

I've got a ListBox that is bound to a custom class:

```
public class SelectionModel : BaseNotifyProperyChanged
{
    private bool _selected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
         get { return _selected; }
         set
         {
             _selected = value;
             base.RaisePropertyChanged( "IsSelected" );
         }
    }
    //.... 
}
```

Through a implementation in the xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

I want to disable selection from the user-interface only, keeping the data binding intact, is this possible? I know that I can disable selection by disabling the ListBoxItems with a style, but this makes the binding void.

Edit: It seems to be some confusion, so I'll clarify. 
I don't want to remove the selection or highlight, **I want to be able to select items programmatically, but not through the user-interface.** So disabling items or changing highligh colors is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What happens if you add a trigger that sets `IsSelected` to a one-way binding?

Comment: Still able to select items through the user-interface.

Comment: not sure I understand right, you want to remove the highlight for selected item, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you disable it?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I honestly thought I tried this, but apparently not! This works flawlessly, thank you!